# Использование Git без хостинга

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Есть 2 человека в команде. Использовать github нет возможности из-за ограничений сервиса. Как можно использовать git без сторонних хостингов? Только наши 2 компьютера подключенные к интернету в разных частях мира.

Comment: Если не можете из одного компьютера залезть на диск другого, то никак. Если устроит какой-нибудь сервис синхронизации типа дропбокса, то можно.

Comment: Поднять сервер gitlab ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Разместил Git репозиторий локально, затем синхронизировал папку с помощью гугл диска (можно любой другой сервис). Чтобы работать с ним использовал

Создать локальный репозиторий (его нужно будет синхронизировать диском): git init --bare

Чтобы работать с ним как с тем что на GitHub (на других компах нужно будет выполнить эту команду, предварительно загрузив папку локального репозитория с диска): git clone (директория локального репозитория)

Далее пользуемся как обычно, синхронизацией займется гугл диск

Comment: А тем временем Gentoo Linux и его форки заменяют rsync на git

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, это как можно rsync на git заменить? Делают симлинк? :)

Comment: @TotalPusher, точно не знаю как оно под капотом, знаю что портаджи (куча мелких текстовых файлов с информацией о доступных версиях программ) синхронизируется между сервером и пользовательской машиной git'ом, а не rsync'ом как раньше.

Comment: Это не будет лучшим решением, потому что нет всех функций, для которых создан гит.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ, который не требует никаких настроек - это использование механизма патчей.

На машине, где были созданы изменения выполняется команда

```
git format-patch <commit-reference>
```

`<commit-reference>` коммит, с которого формируются изменения (сам не попадает).

Полученный файл `.patch` отправляется по почте.

У получателя применяется патч

```
git apply <file-name>
```

Единственное осталось договорится между собой.

[Официальная документация](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)

Answer (score -3):

В принципе git можно использовать на локальном компьютере - github это всего лишь онлайн сервис для использования git. git - это своеобразный язык программирования, который реализован в виде интернет сервиса github.

Пишите в командной строке для установки git

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Заходите по ссылке [для дополнительной информации](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
Вводите pwd для того, чтоб узнать в какой директории вы находитесь и используйте cd и mkdir для создания и перемещения между папками(директориями)

Введите

```
git
```

При успешной загрузке вы увидите большое количество текста, если установили неправильно, то выведется ошибка.

```
git init
```

Это команда требуется для создания git репозитории, где возможна работа

Приведу полезные ресурсы, где можно больше узнать по теме.
[Хороший пост про локальную работу с git на Хабр](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/359216/)
[Полный курс с нуля с объяснением основных концепций git и github](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZF9C0YMKuns9sLDzK6zoiV)

Comment: Вы видимо не увидели вопрос. Не спрашивал как создать репозиторий и что такое git.

Comment: @MLedlum в первой ссылке с Хабр как раз про это написано